# Android Relative/LinearLayout always in middle, no matter if horizontal or vertical

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

This image http://postimg.org/image/h8akuq9gz/ should give you an idea of what I want.
No matter if the device is in vertical or horizontal position, this two "circles" must be always in the mid.

I really don't know how can I achieve this. Can you point me the direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use gravity on root layout, like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

 <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This one is the right answer. I must now adapt it to my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     gravity="center">

             <--Other contorls you want to keep in center-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: the example is for image button but you can try it as per your wish

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/findme"></ImageButton>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I want to be able to put two Imagebutton. If I say "centerInParent" to those two, they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_btn1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/img_1">
   </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_btn2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/img_2">
   </ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The ImageButton overlap the other.

Comment: Remove this property `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. It will surely work.